# upward SOQL burps on some fields but not others

Tags: apex-code

v48

Trying to craft an upward query from Task up to Contact up to Account and hitting a snag.

```
SELECT task.Id, task.Email_Direction__c, task.Who.Id, task.Who.FirstName, task.Owner.UserRoleId FROM task WHERE task.Who.type = 'Contact'
```

works great but

```
SELECT task.Id, task.Email_Direction__c, task.Who.Id, task.Who.Last_Contact_Made__c, task.Owner.UserRoleId FROM task WHERE task.Who.type = 'Contact'
```

does not like Last_Contact_Made__c , which is a field on Contact. Why is this, and what must I change to get it to work?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

You basically have an issue with a [polymorphic field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm).

The SOQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Email_Direction__c,
    Who.Id,
    Owner.UserRoleId,
    TYPEOF Who
        WHEN Account THEN
            Last_Contact_Made__c
FROM
    Task
WHERE
    Who.Type = 'Contact'
```